# An alternate connotation of よかった？

Tags: grammar

I am playing through the Toradora visual novel, and the context is that Ryuuji had lost his memory and doesn't remember his own name. When his friend, Taiga, calls him "Ryuuji," he says:

> その。。。『りゅうじ』というのは、俺の名前でよかったか？

I understand that he is saying: "Ryuuji," is that my name?

But I don't understand why よかった is used here. Usually I think of よかった as "thank goodness," "it was good," or "would have been good." This context doesn't seem to match up with the regular よかった that I'm used to seing. Or perhaps am I just over-thinking this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

良い has some meanings. 良い in this case means "right" and "correct", so 『りゅうじ』というのは、俺の名前でよかったか? is translated as "Was it right that りゅうじ is my name?".

For example, この食べ物は健康に良い is translated as "This food is good for health" and this 良い means "good".

あなたの探している本は、この本で良いですか? is perhaps translated as " Is this book right? The book which you are looking for is." and this 良い means "right".